# How to split a string in Ruby and get all items except the first one?

Tags: ruby, string, split

String is
`ex="test1, test2, test3, test4, test5"`

when I use

```
ex.split(",").first
```

it returns

```
"test1"
```

Now I want to get the remaining items, i.e.  `"test2, test3, test4, test5". If I use

```
ex.split(",").last
```

it returns only

```
"test5"
```

How to get all the remaining items skipping first one?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Try this:

```
first, *rest = ex.split(/, /)
```

Now `first` will be the first value, `rest` will be the rest of the array.

Comment: In what version of Ruby? I tried it in 1.8.7 and `rest` only contains "test2".

Comment: probably meant `first,*rest = ex.split(/,/)`

Comment: Yep, I could not test my line at the time. `first, *rest = ex.split(/,/)` was indeed what I meant. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Another way is to get a range from the resulting array.  `things = ex.split(/,/); things[1..-1]`

Answer (score 44):

```
ex.split(',', 2).last
```

The 2 at the end says: split into 2 pieces, not more.

normally split will cut the value into as many pieces as it can, using a second value you can limit how many pieces you will get. Using `ex.split(',', 2)` will give you:

```
["test1", "test2, test3, test4, test5"]
```

as an array, instead of:

```
["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"]
```

Comment: Downside is you'd have to `split` again if you want all but the first values as an array rather than a string. Still a nice trick.

Also, using `ex.split(',', 2).last` would not return the array you mention, only its last value, right?

Comment: Copy-Paste mistake haha, fixed it

Answer (score 15):

Since you've got an array, what you *really* want is [`Array#slice`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002205), not `split`.

```
rest = ex.slice(1 .. -1)
# or
rest = ex[1 .. -1]
```

Comment: So with a string you'd want `ex.split(/, /).slice(1..-1)` to get all but the first elements, assuming you're not interested in the first value.

Answer (score 9):

You probably mistyped a few things. From what I gather, you start with a string such as:

```
string = "test1, test2, test3, test4, test5"
```

Then you want to split it to keep only the significant substrings:

```
array = string.split(/, /)
```

And in the end you only need all the elements excluding the first one:

```
# We extract and remove the first element from array
first_element = array.shift

# Now array contains the expected result, you can check it with
puts array.inspect
```

Did that answer your question ?

Answer (score 8):

Sorry a bit late to the party and a bit surprised that nobody mentioned the [drop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Array.html#method-i-drop) method:

```
ex="test1, test2, test3, test4, test5"
ex.split(",").drop(1).join(",")
=> "test2,test3,test4,test5"
```

Answer (score 6):

```
ex="test1,test2,test3,test4,test5"
all_but_first=ex.split(/,/)[1..-1]
```

Answer (score 5):

if u want to use them as an array u already knew, else u can use every one of them as a different parameter ...
try this :

```
parameter1,parameter2,parameter3,parameter4,parameter5 = ex.split(",")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this:

```
String is ex="test1, test2, test3, test4, test5"
array = ex.split(/,/)
array.size.times do |i|
  p array[i]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `split(",")[i]` where `i` is the index in result array. `split` gives array below

```
["test1", " test2", " test3", " test4", " test5"]
```

whose element can be accessed by index.