# I need to read file and save to type o things

Tags: ruby

I need to read a text file like this,

```
regular: 12/04/2013, 13/04/2013
```

extract `'regular'`, and save it in a variable and all the dates in an array. How can I do this?

Comment: I've tried to split the line and save in variable like this:  `@costumer_request = line.delete(',').split` to create and array of that line and then: `@costumer = @costumer_request[0]` to save 'regular' in a variable. I don't know how to get the rest of the array and put into another.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333347/how-to-use-stringsplit-in-ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you say you tried, would the following do what you want?

```
data = line.split(/: */)             # => ["regular", "12/04/2013, 13/04/2013"]
@customer = data[0]                  # => "regular"
@dates_array = data[1].split(/, */)  # => ["12/04/2013", "13/04/2013"]
```

I used * to match (and eliminate) multiple blanks.  I'm assuming here that you don't want the blanks, comma, or the colon (:) separator included in your results.  If that's not correct, adjust the regular expressions accordingly.

Comment: This what I've been looking for. Thank you :)